# Import dump file

Tags: sql, oracle

I am totally new in oracle world and need help.
I installed oracle free version OracleXE112_Win64 and has got a dump file that I need to import. 
Is there anyone who can guide me how to do it?
Thank's

---

Can someone tell me what happens here when I import the dump file. I get the following:

```
Username: system 
Password: 
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production Import data only (yes/no): no > yes
Import file: EXPDAT.DMP > C:\Buildings22.dmp 
Enter insert buffer size (minimum is 8192) 30720> 30720 
Export file created by EXPORT:V11.01.00 via conventional path
Warning: the objects were exported by Buildings22, not by you
import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
List contents of import file only (yes/no): no > yes
IMP-00402: Invalid parameter "SHOW" with data_only mode 
IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully
```

How can I check if I import a dump file? 
How can I display the content of dump file, tables in Oracle SQL Developer?
I apologize for the issues, but I really brand new in oracle?

Comment: I do not know which tool has been used to generate the file, but it's comme from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production. It's exported with character set WE8MSWIN1252 and AL16UTF16 NCHAR. Is it enough information?

Comment: The question is: was the export created with (the deprecated) `exp` tool or with the `expdp` tool?

Comment: I found out that it is generated with exp tool

Comment: you told it to only list the contents, take the default 'No' on that last prompt...more importantly, are you in an all English character world? If not, the warning about the characterset conversion isn't something you should ignore